# How to retrieve translations of CustomList items in NetSuite using SuiteTalk?

Tags: java, soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I have a custom list in NetSuite containing values in English. Each item in the list is also translated in French.

I am able to retrieve the list items using the following code in Java with the SuiteTalk SOAP client:

```
RecordRef recordRef = new RecordRef();
recordRef.setInternalId("123");
recordRef.setType(RecordType.customList);
CustomList list = (CustomList) wsClient.getRecord(recordRef);
```

However the returned list only contains values in English and I also would like to retrieve corresponding translations in French.

How can I achieve that ?